# c# - inherit behaviour for controls added at run time

Tags: c#, wpf

What I want to achieve is to be able to move, at run time, controls placed on a canvas. At the moment it is working but I would like to be able to add controls (such as textblocks or labels) at run time and those controls to have the same behaviour of the controls added at the design time.

This is the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="Behaviour.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:i="clr
```

namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:Behaviour"

```
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Height="271" 
            Margin="49,28,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="443"
            Background="Beige">



            <Label Content="Label" Canvas.Left="47" Canvas.Top="100">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <custom:DragInCanvasBehaviour>
                    </custom:DragInCanvasBehaviour>

                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Label>

            <Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100"
                 Canvas.Left="275" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="41" 
              Width="100">

                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <custom:DragInCanvasBehaviour/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

            </Ellipse>

            <TextBlock Text="Drag meeee">
             <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <custom:DragInCanvasBehaviour/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TextBlock>

        <Label Content="Label" 
               Canvas.Left="186" 
               Canvas.Top="18">

            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>

            <custom:DragInCanvasBehaviour>
            </custom:DragInCanvasBehaviour>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Label>


     </Canvas>

  </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the code behind the window...

```
namespace Behaviour
{
public class DragInCanvasBehaviour : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    bool IsDragging = false;
    Point MouseOffSet;
    Canvas cnv;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.MouseMove += AssociatedObject_MouseMove;
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonUp += 
AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonUp;
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown += 
AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown += (s, e) => 
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Clicked!");
    }
    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.MouseMove -= AssociatedObject_MouseMove;
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonUp -= 
AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonUp;
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown -= 
AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown;
    }


    protected void AssociatedObject_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs 
e)
    {
        if (IsDragging)
        {
            Point pt = e.GetPosition(cnv);
            // Move element
           // AssociatedObject.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, pt.Y - 
MouseOffSet.Y);
            //AssociatedObject.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, pt.X - 
MouseOffSet.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(AssociatedObject, pt.Y - MouseOffSet.Y);
            Canvas.SetLeft(AssociatedObject, pt.X - MouseOffSet.X); ;
        }
    }
    protected void AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, 
MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsDragging)
        {
            AssociatedObject.ReleaseMouseCapture();
            IsDragging = false;
        }
    }
    protected void AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, 
MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cnv == null)
        {
            cnv = (Canvas)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(AssociatedObject);
        }

        IsDragging = true;
        MouseOffSet = e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject);
        AssociatedObject.CaptureMouse();

    }

  }


}
```

As I said, this is working fine and doing what Im after. But id like to do this for each control added at runtime.

Thanks!

Comment: Before asking a question, please make sure you have read the [ask] topics. Now you have described what you want. Alright, that's fine. So where is your specific question or a particular problem?

Comment: I would like to register the dragging behaviour from the code above to controls added at run time in the canvas.

At the moment, if I want a control to be dragged (moved) in the canvas I have to assign it that behaviour

    
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>

            <custom:DragInCanvasBehaviour>
            </custom:DragInCanvasBehaviour>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

Since I am adding controls at runtime, I d like these new controls to inherit the same dragging behaviour.